# Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.myapp. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hi I'm having this error I already informed FirebaseApp.initializeApp (this); oncreate and I'm still having an error. can anybody help me?

I have tried several solution alternatives found right here on the stackoverflow but have not been successful in any of them. any help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private ProgressDialog loadingBar;

    private Button LoginButton, PhoneLoginButton;
    private EditText UserEmail, UserPassword;
    private TextView NeedNewAccountLink, ForgetPasswordLink;

    private DatabaseReference UsersRef;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        UsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
        InitializeFields();


        NeedNewAccountLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                SendUserToRegisterActivity();
            }
        });


        LoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                AllowUserToLogin();
            }
        });


    }




    @Override
    protected void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser != null)
        {
            SendUserToMainActivity();
        }
    }



    private void AllowUserToLogin()
    {
        String email = UserEmail.getText().toString();
        String password = UserPassword.getText().toString();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email))
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter email...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password))
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter password...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            loadingBar.setTitle("Sign In");
            loadingBar.setMessage("Please wait....");
            loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
            loadingBar.show();

            mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task)
                        {
                            if (task.isSuccessful())
                            {
                                String currentUserId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                                String deviceToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

                                UsersRef.child(currentUserId).child("device_token")
                                        .setValue(deviceToken)
                                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)
                                            {
                                                if (task.isSuccessful())
                                                {
                                                    SendUserToMainActivity();
                                                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Logged in Successful...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                    loadingBar.dismiss();
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                String message = task.getException().toString();
                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error : " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                loadingBar.dismiss();
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    }



    private void InitializeFields()
    {
        LoginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        PhoneLoginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.phone_login_button);
        UserEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_email);
        UserPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_password);
        NeedNewAccountLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.need_new_account_link);
        ForgetPasswordLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.forget_password_link);
        loadingBar = new ProgressDialog(this);
    }



    private void SendUserToMainActivity()
    {
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(mainIntent);
        finish();
    }

    private void SendUserToRegisterActivity()
    {
        Intent registerIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
        startActivity(registerIntent);
    }
}
```

build.app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.2.2'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.+'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

Build project

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
        
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

LogCat

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.myapp. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getInstance(Unknown Source)
        at com.myapp.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:46)
```

Comment: Have you tried to add `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`, as the last line in your biuld.gradle Module:app file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a MApplication.class

```
public class MApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);

    }
```

And Add this in Manifest

```
<application
        android:name=".MApplication">
```

Final step add in top of the build.gradle(app level)

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Please explain why do you need hardware acceleration

Comment: Sorry that is not needed

Comment: add this in top the app modue build.gradle ```apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Just apply this `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`